# Add calendar shortcut in left link bar?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, shortcut

Is it possible to keep the marked left calendar view in the left link bar permanently?
So that it is visible from any page/list view on the subsite?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I know you can't do it. 
You can try 3-rd party solutions, and then add calendar in your master page layout.